# Increasing number variable value in a loop [Python]

Tags: python

New to the python langugage and programming so I have a newb question. I have a keyboard input that i am tracking using a variable called key. I need to take a count of how many times this key is hit [ like a piece of percussion/drum]. I want to have a variable named 'count' that I can print and everytime the key is hit, it increases the value of the count variable by one. So far this is the nearest I could get. Any help would be appreciated

Example code:

```
count = 0

if key == 'e':

    for x in range(10):

        count = x

        print(count)

return
```

Comment: your line should be: `count += 1`. And why the for loop? That doesn't seem to be necessary or correct.

Comment: well, that would be as simple as `count = count + 1` or more neatly `count += 1`

Comment: Also mate, you don't need a ```return``` statement here. Return statements are generally used for functions or methods